# Поддомены Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Создала второй сайт, как сделать чтобы он открывался как поддомен
**moscow.mysite.ru**, а не так **mysite.ru/moscow/**? Сейчас при открытии moscow.mysite.ru выводится как главный сайт mysite.ru, а не из папки /moscow/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Многосайтовость на разных доменах: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=103&LESSON_ID=287